# Nextjs hydration error when I change language

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, i18next

I have a nextjs project `v12.2.4` and it provides internationalization using  i18next. In particulare I handle 2 languages: *Italian* and *English*. **When I use English language the app throws me the following errors**, while in Italian everything seems to be all right.

```
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
    at checkForUnmatchedText (react-dom.development.js?ac89:9647:1)
    at diffHydratedProperties (react-dom.development.js?ac89:10310:1)
    at hydrateInstance (react-dom.development.js?ac89:11306:1)
    at prepareToHydrateHostInstance (react-dom.development.js?ac89:12564:1)
    at completeWork (react-dom.development.js?ac89:22181:1)
    at completeUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?ac89:26596:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?ac89:26568:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js?ac89:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js?ac89:26434:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js?ac89:25738:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js?bcd2:266:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js?bcd2:239:1)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js?bcd2:533:1)
checkForUnmatchedText @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:9647
diffHydratedProperties @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:10310
hydrateInstance @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:11306
prepareToHydrateHostInstance @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:12564
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:22181
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:26596
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:26568
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js?bcd2:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js?bcd2:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js?bcd2:533
3react-dom.development.js?ac89:12507

Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
    at throwOnHydrationMismatch (react-dom.development.js?ac89:12507:1)
    at tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance (react-dom.development.js?ac89:12520:1)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js?ac89:19902:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?ac89:21618:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js?ac89:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?ac89:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js?ac89:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js?ac89:26434:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js?ac89:25738:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js?bcd2:266:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js?bcd2:239:1)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js?bcd2:533:1)
throwOnHydrationMismatch @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:12507
tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:12520
updateHostComponent @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:19902
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:21618
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js?bcd2:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js?bcd2:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js?bcd2:533
react-dom.development.js?ac89:19849

Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
    at updateHostRoot (react-dom.development.js?ac89:19849:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?ac89:21615:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js?ac89:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?ac89:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js?ac89:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js?ac89:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js?ac89:25850:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js?ac89:25750:1)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js?bcd2:266:1)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js?bcd2:239:1)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js?bcd2:533:1)
updateHostRoot @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:19849
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:21615
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js?ac89:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js?bcd2:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js?bcd2:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js?bcd2:533
```

Of course I checked it out on the already answered questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71706064/react-18-hydration-failed-because-the-initial-ui-does-not-match-what-was-render) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71847117/error-hydration-failed-because-the-initial-ui-does-not-match-what-was-rendered)), but I couldn't find anything for my case. I believe the reason for this error is i18next which server side it is in Italian while client side is in English so it says that *it doesn't match*.

This is my `i18n.ts` file:

```
import i18n, { StringMap, TOptions } from 'i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import { initReactI18next, useTranslation as i18nextUseTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import postProcessor from 'i18next-sprintf-postprocessor';
import en from '../public/locales/en/translation.json';
import it from '../public/locales/it/translation.json';

export const resources: Resources = {
  en: {
    translation: en,
  },
  it: {
    translation: it,
  },
};

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(postProcessor)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: ['it', 'en'],
    debug: false,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    defaultNS,
    resources,
    react: {
      useSuspense: false,
    },
  });
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this error?

Comment: Why aren't you using next-i18next?

Comment: react-i18next. Yeah I use it!

Comment: I mean https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next

Comment: Uh all right GG. I haven't seen this before yet.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by avoiding to return the app at the first render.

`app.tsx`

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  //at the first render initialRenderComplete is false
  const [initialRenderComplete, setInitialRenderComplete] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInitialRenderComplete(true);
  }, []);

  if (!initialRenderComplete) return <></>;

  return (
    <>
      <GlobalContext.Provider value={global?.attributes}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
      </GlobalContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: While this may solve the hydration errors, it's not a good solution. This will prevent server-side rendering for the whole app, defeating the purpose of using Next.js in the first place. Look into integrating `next-i18next` into your Next.js app which handles translation properly with SSR/SSG. See the official examples: https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/tree/master/examples/simple.

Comment: Thank you @juliomalves! I just replaced react-i18next with next-i18next and everything seems to be all right!